# Firebird exception: Table unknown

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird2.5

I could establish the connection to a Firebird database with the following connection string:

```
ConnectionString = "User ID=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=localhost:C:\\MyDb\\mydb.FDB;DataSource=localhost;Charset=NONE;";
```

But when the C# code tries to execute the query the following error comes:

> Dynamic SQL Error SQL Error Code = -204 **Table unknown**

The code that I've tried:

```
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
...
FbConnection connection = new FbConnection(ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
FbCommand readCommand = new FbCommand("Select Name From Customer;", connection);
FbDataReader myreader = readCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

There definitely exists the Customer table (I've checked with IBExpert - in that I can read the data). I hardly found anything on Google.

Firebird 2.5 server is running on my Computer. What could be the problem?

Comment: The error is incomplete; a "Table unkown"-error will also display the name of the unknown table. Could you also show the DDL of the table? I suspect you created a table `"Customer"` which is case sensitive and therefor distinct from `Customer` (which is case insensitive and equivalent to `CUSTOMER`).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the DDL. An FDB file was sent to me as the database without any more information. Only thing I could use is IBExpert (to see what tables are in it). Can I figure out the DDL somehow from the database itself, or with some tools?

Comment: Sure, IBExpert can reverse engineer the DDL (as can other tools). As I don't use IBExpert, I don't exactly know how.

Comment: Yes, I've just checked, and unfortunately it's "Customer".

Comment: To view the DDL from `IBFExpert` open the table or stored procedure or something else and just click on `DDL` tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you confirmed in the comments that the table name is actually `"Customer"`, you will need to quote the object names in your query to make them case sensitive, so:

```
new FbCommand("Select \"Name\" From \"Customer\"", connection);
```

I have assumed that `Name` is also case sensitive, and therefor quoted it as well.

Comment: This solved the problem. Thank you a lot!